# Excel: Dynamic cell reference for Roulette

Tags: excel, excel-formula, roulette-wheel-selection

I try to build a roulette (0-36) and have a question regarding cell reference: I would like to define what happens when someone is betting on Red and that excel will apply the definition of red only when needed. (More general: I would like to define all roulette betting options such as Odd, Column bet, Corner etc. and apply the definition when needed.)

[image]

Look at the image: Two people are betting on Red, but only one result is correct: D2 (as a correct Red bet will double). D3 is not doubled and, therefore, it is wrong.

**Formulas**:

D2: `=IF(B2="Red";`**C5**`;IF(B2="Black";C6;C2))` In this formula I would like to reference the underlying formula C5 what is working. (In this scenario only the part `B3="Red";C5`is relevant.)

D3: `=IF(B3="Red";`**C5**`;IF(B3="Black";C6;C3))` In this formula I would like to reference the underlying formula C5 what does NOT work. (In this scenario only the part `B3="Red";C5`is relevant.)

C5: `=IF(OR($A$2=1;$A$2=3;$A$2=5;$A$2=7;$A$2=9;$A$2=12;$A$2=14;$A$2=16;$A$2=18;$A$2=19;$A$2=21;$A$2=23;$A$2=25;$A$2=27;$A$2=30;$A$2=32;$A$2=34;$A$2=36);`**C2*2;-C2**`)`

**The (supposed) problem**: That the C5 formula is referenced to C2 (see last two elements).

**My goal**: Whenever there is a "Red" entry in the Bet section (e.g. column B) it will apply the (corrected) `Definition Red C5`. In order to do that the part `C2*2;-C2`of the C5 formula must change according to the cell where the "Red" bet is: Whether B2 or B10 is "Red" it should apply the underlying formula. And, it should apply the correct formula for multiple bets like in my example.

I hope you understand what I try to say. Would be happy if anyone can help me:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding everything properly, it might not be possible to use a single cell for the winning amount `C5` and the losing amount `C6`.  The reason is, there will be a different winning amount and losing amount each time based on the bet.  That's why Row 2 is working.  It uses the Row 2 stake `C2` in the winning amount formula `C5`.  You could get Row 3 to work by using `C3*2; -C3` in the winning amount formula `C5`, but then `D2` would be broken instead!

Here are two screen shots using Excel 2010 that might help (this was also tested in LibreOffice 5.1.6.2).  This is a partial solution, though it is admittedly not the best.  However, the idea should work using built-in functions (no VBA).

### Example 1

[image: Excel 2010 Worksheet with results from a roulette of 2]

### Example 2

[image: Excel 2010 Worksheet with results from a roulette of 33]

## Remarks

This solution requires that an exhaustive list of bet types be constructed (Column I) along with the payout multiplier if the bettor's bet type ends up being a winner (Column K).  Column J contains the calculations for whether or not the resulting number `A2` results in a win (`TRUE`) or loss (`FALSE`) for the Bet Type.  The calculations I used for the examples shown are:

- Red: `=OR($A$2=1,$A$2=3,$A$2=5,$A$2=7,$A$2=9,$A$2=12,$A$2=14,$A$2=16,$A$2=18,$A$2=19,$A$2=21,$A$2=23,$A$2=25,$A$2=27,$A$2=30,$A$2=32,$A$2=34,$A$2=36)`

  - Perhaps a [cleaner alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8618168/684617): `=OR($A$2={1,3,5,7,9,12,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,27,30,32,34,36})`
- Black: `=OR($A$2=2,$A$2=4,$A$2=6,$A$2=8,$A$2=10,$A$2=11,$A$2=13,$A$2=15,$A$2=17,$A$2=20,$A$2=22,$A$2=24,$A$2=26,$A$2=28,$A$2=29,$A$2=31,$A$2=33,$A$2=35)`

  - Perhaps a [cleaner alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8618168/684617): `=OR($A$2={2,4,6,8,10,11,13,15,17,20,22,24,26,28,29,31,33,35})`
- Low: `=AND($A$2>=1,$A$2<=18)`
- High: `=AND($A$2>=19,$A$2<=36)`
- Odd: `=MOD($A$2,2)=1`
- Even: `=MOD($A$2,2)=0`
- 1st Dozen: `=AND($A$2>=1,$A$2<=12)`
- 2nd Dozen: `=AND($A$2>=13,$A$2<=24)`
- 3rd Dozen: `=AND($A$2>=25,$A$2<=36)`

I'm no roulette expert so I might not have them quite right... But I'm guessing you know the winning formulas already.

The problem with my approach is that creating the exhaustive list of wins (Columns I, J, and K) will take a lot of effort.  There might be a more elegant solution, but I'd have to think more about it.

---

Now you can take each bettor's bet type (Column B) and find its corresponding index from the set of all bet types (`I2:I10`) using the `MATCH` function.  The results of this process are shown in Column C.  Column D is just an illustration of the formula, so you don't need to include it in your spreadsheet.

Once you have the index, you can use it along with the `INDEX` function to look in `J2:J10` to see if the bet type is a winner or not.  If it's a winner, you can also use the index to find the appropriate Payout Multiplier from `K2:K10` and multiply it by the stake in Column E.  If it's not a winner, the result is the loss of the stake.  The results of this process are shown in Column F.  Column G is just an illustration of the formula, so you don't need to include it in your spreadsheet.

Keep in mind that the Column I, J, and K ranges will need to expand as you add more bet types.  So instead of `I2:I10`, `J2:J10`, and `K2:K10`, you'll end up with larger ranges.

I explained the `MATCH` and `INDEX` functions a little more thoroughly in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49828037/684617), though you'd probably be even better served just looking them up in an online manual somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It took me a little  time to understand MATCH and INDEX. And one more point for fully understanding: Do we use the MATCH function to get the row of the payout multiplier? (Is there an error in the example result formula? Shouldn`t it be "K" instead of "J" in the second INDEX?)

Comment: @Philip Good observation!  I did have an error in the "Result Formula" column.  I think it was because I added a column after putting the text in there and I forgot to reset the text.  I'll update the screen shots, but the first `INDEX` (over `J2:J10`) determines if the bet was a win or a loss.  Then the second `INDEX` (over `K2:K10`) gets the payout multiplier for the `TRUE` case (i.e. the winning case).  I apologize for the error.

Comment: @Philip Also, you are correct that the `MATCH` function essentially gets the right row to use based on the Bet Type.  For each Bet in Column B, it finds the corresponding Bet Type from cells `I2:I10` and returns the corresponding index... So, "Red" should return an index of `1`, "Black" should return an index of `2`, Low should return an index of `3`, etc.  Those index values are then used with the `INDEX` function as explained above to determine if the bet was a winning bet and the payout multiplier if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the update, thanks for your answer in the comments and thanks again for your solution. It is working beautifully:-)